# Install assets from app directory

Tags: symfony, assets

Here is my directory structure

```
/app/Resources/public
/app/Resources/public/css
/app/Resources/public/iamges
/app/Resources/public/js
```

I need to install these assets to */web* directory. What is the right way to do it?
I've tried `app/console install:assets` but it installs assets only from bundles. Is it possible to store global assets in app directory?

Comment: This is not possible in the core Symfony framework. The `assets:install` command searches in all bundles and not in de `app` directory. You can however create your own command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your global assets should go directly into the web folder. There is no need to put them in the app folder and then copy them!

The `install:assets` or `assetic:dump` command are for assets which belong to one bundle only and which are kept inside this bundle to make them reusable.

What you can do though is to keep the assets which belong to your application in your "application bundle". Most of the time you got at least one bundle which is not reusable, representing your application core. I keep my base templates (`base.html.twig`) and the main assets in there so I can use `assetic:dump` on them!

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to store asserts together with global templates.

Comment: True that assets:install is for bundles only, but false that assetic:dump is. The later processes any file you reference, wherever they are. It has, however, a shortcut notation working only with bundles (@). But generally you are right: if it's not reusable, put it where you want, it's your app afterall :)

Comment: I'm agree, the best way is put them in AppBundle