# Symfony assetic cssrewrite image path in app/Resources

Tags: php, css, image, symfony, assetic

I've got a problem with assetic and the path of my images in CSS on Symfony.
My base template, my base CSS, and the images used in this CSS are in the folder app/Resources.

I have this:

```
app/
    Resources/
        public/
            css/
                base.css
            images/
                mybackground.png
    views/
        base.html.twig
```

In the file `base.css`, I want to load the file `mybackground.css` as a background, so I have this line:

`background-image: url('../images/mybackground.png');`

And in the file 'base.html.twig', I load the css with:

```
{% stylesheets '@base_css' filter='cssrewrite' %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" media="all" href="{{ asset_url }}" />

{% endstylesheets %}
```

I also tried without the filter `cssrewrite`.

In `app/config/config.yml`, I have this:

```
assetic:
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
assets:
    base_css:
        inputs:
            - '../app/Resources/public/css/base.css'
```

Before try, I used all of these commands:

```
php app/console cache:clear
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
php app/console assetic:dump
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

As you can guess, my background image isn't loaded (the browser returns a 404 not found error).
I searched a lot on internet, and I found similar cases but with the resources in some bundles not in app/Resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a `public` directory in the `Resources` directory of your bundle, and run the `assets:install --symlink` command, a symbolic link is created in the `web/bundles` directory, corresponding to the name of your bundle.

Also, to retrieve your image, you should use the relative path of the web directory instead of the absolute path of your asset, which is :

```
/bundles/bundlename/images/background.jpg
```

**EDIT**

If you really doesn't want to place them inside a bundle, just move them from the `app/Resources` directly to the `web` folder, and call it in your css using :

```
url('/images/background.jpg');
```

See [symfony2 how to access app/Resources/img from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982476/symfony2-how-to-access-app-resources-img-from-browser)

Comment: Thank you, but these resources aren't in the folder Resources of a bundle but in app/Resources, and no directory created in web/bundles, that's why I don't know what do to.

Comment: you are missing sth. take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785121/install-assets-from-app-directory

Comment: I've added changes, the only solution is to move them from app/resources directly in the web folder. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785121/install-assets-from-app-directory and the link in my answer

Comment: That's what I did, I moved the file in web/images  I just thought there was a better way to do it.
But at least it works, thank you.

Comment: I agree. I was very surprised by the comportment of the command which doesn't handle the assets from the global `Resources` directory.

Answer (score 0):

after calling assets:install and assetic:dump you will find your files in the web-directory (webservers document root)  all files NOT in /web are not accesible by httpd so just take a look at your /web folder and look inside the bundles folder

so the relative path would be

```
/bundles/bundlename/images/background.jpg
```

this you can use in your css file

Comment: Thank you but no directory is created in /web/bundles. And that's logic, because my resources aren't in a bundle but in app/Resources...

Comment: Assets placed in `app/Resources` are not linked to the `bundles` directory when the `assets:install` command is called. Also, he have to put the assets directly into the web directory.